# Allow Comments In Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I'm creating book web shop in Orchard. I have other project where admin is adding books in database. What I want to add is comments Part on Detail Page for some book. I know how to add Comments in Dashboard
 but my problem is how to connect the comments with the book, because when i add comments all comments are displayed on Detail Page. For example if some user open detail Page for "Anna Karenina" and add comment "Best book" this comment is displayed on Detail Page for all books. The problem is that I have only one Detail Page where in the url I have bookId.

Comment: So you're saying you have one content item that is used for the display of every book, depending on the bookId in the url? Comments are attached to a single content item, and you only have one it seems. How is your book content item architecture set up?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't look like a good idea. Still, if you must do it this way, you always have the option of using an external comment system such as Disqus.